# How to create smooth transition (animation) of layouts

Tags: java, ios, swift, android-layout, animation

I have designed my app for both Android and iOS. Now I need to create smooth transitions like in this app. [Video of app](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gFUQ182HT0g) .I need it for both devices. Can anyone link me some tutorial, video or just documentation? Because everything what I have managed to do was flashy animations, no the smooth one. Thanks for answers.

Comment: Show what you have done so far.

Comment: https://vimeo.com/214888386 Check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic principle is that you include the target parameter(s) you want to animate within the UIView.animate function, while you need define them before and after. 
You have the phase before the function call (consider it keyframe 1 in animation terms) and you have the phase you target for after animation (keyframe 2) like so:

**Phase(s) before:**

```
self.yourView.opacity = 0.5
self.yourView.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
```

**Phase(s) after:**

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: { 
self.yourView.opacity = 1.0
self.yourView.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)
})
```

The simplest starting point used above and a version with more options (you can also introduce spring behaviours and things):

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: { 
// your code for animation(s) here.
})

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: { 
// your code for animation(s) here
}, completion: nil)
```

**This is a nice intro on UIView animations:**
https://medium.com/written-code/ui-animations-with-swift-2ebb5e6d2292

**And a more complex use of it with additional physics and the whole palette:**
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hbuL-vUDBhg&t=1834s

This is my first answer - hope it helps.

Comment: Great answer mate. It is enough to get started. Thanks